# how to rename the Table based on the input in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm new to mysql.
This is my table. Table name: `LOGDATETIME`:

```
2012-05-30   17:26:33  
2012-05-30   17:26:33
2012-05-30   17:26:33
2012-05-31   17:26:33
2012-05-31   17:27:22
2012-05-31   17:27:22 
2012-05-31   17:27:22
2012-06-01   00:08:12
2012-06-02   00:08:12
2012-06-06   00:08:12
```

I need to rename this table name based on the date. For example `LOGDATETIME_2012_05_30_TO_2012_06_06`. For this I need to write stored procedure in mysql. But I don't know how to write .

Can any one please help me.

Answer (score 2):

SO isn't really here to *give* you the answers. We should be pointing you in the right direction.

Have a look at `MAX` and `MIN` of the date field for the file name. Using `DATE_FORMAT` to get the correct format. Then use `RENAME TABLE` to perform the table name change. Next time provide some code that you have tried yourself.

Comment: As I said it's not about us doing the work for them. People learn nothing that way. He has been given the tools, now he can get his own solution.

Answer (score 0):

Work around:

- name tables with index, e.g. table1, table2, table3...
- create information table with table names and their start/end datetimes.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE info_table (
  id INT(11) NOT NULL,
  table_name VARCHAR(255),
  start_date DATETIME,
  end_date DATETIME,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```